# Returned variable with no indication in source code

Tags: perl

(I recently decided to learn Perl using O'Reilly *Learning Perl* 6th edition).

Goal: Make a list of numbers from another list that only includes numbers that are larger than the average of the source array. However,

This was provided by the book.

```
my @fred = above_average(1..10);
print "\@fred is @fred\n";
print "(Should be 6 7 8 9 10)\n";

my @barney = above_average(100, 1..10);
print "\@barney is @barney\n";
print "(Should be just 100)\n";
```

This is my response.

```
sub total {
    #computes total of array
}
sub average {
    #computers average from
    #array and length of said array
}

sub above_average {
    $average = average(@_);
    my @ab_avr;
    foreach $num (@_) {
        if ($num > $average) {
            push @ab_avr, $num;
        }
    }
    @ab_avr;
}
```

The first sample seems to be working, however the second sample outputs 100, which is correct, but I do not understand why 100 is being returned at all. The array I passed in into `above_average()` was only the numbers 1 to 10, with the extra parameter 100. Conisdering that the default variable, $_, is never used, why is 100 being shown?

Thanks.

Comment: A couple of style notes, always use `return` to make it explicit what is being returned for the future reader (I hope Learning Perl isn't still teaching implicit returns).  And unless you need a global (which you rarely do) declare all your variables with `my` including `foreach my $num` to limit them to their block scope.  Learning Perl should teach you about [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) which will enforce this.

Comment: `(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+100)/11=14.0909`

Comment: @Schwern Ah, thanks for the style tip. I must have missed the `use` when reading.

Comment: This is the perfect place to use `grep`. `sub above_average { my $average = average(@_); return grep { $_ > $average } @_ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lists and arrays are subtly different](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array?). You can't pass an array to a subroutine; all subroutines take lists and return lists; the entire list that is passed is available in the subroutine as if it were the array `@_`.

In this case, you are passing `100, 1..10`, so `@_` will in fact contain 100, 1, 2, 3, ..., 10.

This isn't actually a problem in your code, but you should try to always use lexicals wherever possible, e.g. `my $average =`, `foreach my $num`, and use strict and warnings.

Comment: The difference between arrays and lists isn't clear to even experienced Perl programmers.  Perhaps you could explain that or link to an explanation?